# How can I read a python list from a text file?

Tags: python

I have a text file that is formatted as a python list ( [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] )
and I would like to read it in python as a list

what could I use to accomplish this?

JSON was recommended to me, but I can't seem to parse the syntax. Is there a better/easier/python-ier way?

Comment: Why not `json.loads(data)`?

Comment: Yeah, that seems correct Farhan.K

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to do this

```
>>> import ast
>>> my_list = ast.literal_eval("[[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]")
>>> print(my_list)
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> print(type(my_list))
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: exactly what I needed! Thanks!